# JAX-WS Metro implementation in Wildfly

Tags: jax-ws, wildfly, wildfly-10

I have tried to change the default (`CXF`) implementation with `JAX-WS Metro` implementation in Wildfly 10. I had to do plenty of steps (followed this [link](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/232745)) and adapted to Wildfly 10.

- disabled webservices subsystem.
- added Metro implementation jars as module
- provided javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider file.
- disabled org.jboss.modules from javax modules.

But on server startup, there is an exception on initialization. Here is the stack trace. It looks like still jboss `__XMLInputFactory` is being instantiated instead of `Metro` one.

any ideas ? I tried to add a file services/javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory with  below class and no luck.

```
com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl
```

**stacktrace**

```
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:231)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(WSServletContainerInitializer.java:66)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:184)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate(WSServletContextListener.java:137)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(WSServletContainerInitializer.java:61)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:144)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate(WSServletContextListener.java:127)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: __redirected.__XMLInputFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory
    at javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance(XMLInputFactory.java:136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.streaming.XMLStreamReaderFactory.getXMLInputFactory(XMLStreamReaderFactory.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.streaming.XMLStreamReaderFactory.<clinit>(XMLStreamReaderFactory.java:78)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: This may be rather difficult to change. It's not generally easy to just replace integrated implementations like this. That said try to make sure you're not including a JAXP libraries in your deployment or as a resource in your modules.

Comment: Thanks. The same ear is deployed in JBoss 7.2 but the application does not work yet. I understand there is whole lot of difference between them. But apparently newer versions are not flexible like old ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this is due to `classloader` issue that `XMLInputFactoryImpl` is loaded in more than one classloader. The steps mentioned in my question does not work in `wildfly` release as it acts different to its predecessor.

I have managed to find my own way to make `Metro` work in `wildfly 10` as below.

> - packaged the metro implementation in the ear itself. And no other module hack needed. (refer pom.xml)
> - removed the default webservice module (refer jboss-deployment-structure.xml)
> - Added JNDI lookup for each EJBs to refer them inside WAR. It looks like CDI injection `@EJB` does not work due to this procedure, hence
>     will have to use JNDI.

**jboss-deployment-structure.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <!-- This means that the sub deployments of the EAR will have automatic 
        dependencies on each other except for WAR sub deployments. -->
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>

    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="webservices" />
            <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <!-- needed for SOAPHandler otherwise not required. -->
        <dependencies>
            <module name="com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj" export="true" services="export" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>

</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.1-b16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>webservices-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1-b16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.tools.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>webservices-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.1-b16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>webservices-extra-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1-b16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>webservices-extra</artifactId>
            <version>2.1-b16</version>
        </dependency>
```

**JNDI lookup**

```
// get the deployed name from startup log for each EJBs deployed
deployedName = "java:global/example-ear-2.0-SNAPSHOT/logic/ExampleBean!org.example.com.ExampleBean";
T ejb = (T) initialContext.lookup(deployedName);
```